# How to show pure file names without parent paths using CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

I have 2 folder and 4 file under those folder like this:

> ```
> C:\test\Folder1\1.txt
> C:\test\Folder1\2.txt
> C:\test\Folder2\3.txt
> C:\test\Folder2\4.txt
> ```

I would like to use to export a text file and list out all file name in test folder like this:

> ```
> 1.txt
> 2.txt
> 3.txt
> 4.txt
> ```

I tried the cmd as below but the file will show with dirictory.

```
dir /S /B *.txt  /a-d >C:\list.txt
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`dir` command](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) shows pure file names only with the `/B` switch, but when `/S` is also specified, full paths are returned.

You have two options in order to not get the parent directories but only the pure file names:

1. Iterate over the whole directory tree using [`for /R`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) and executing `dir /B` in each sub-directory individually:

   ```cmd
   (for /R "C:\test" %%I in (.) do dir /B /A:-D "%%~I\*.txt") > "C:\list.txt"
   ```
2. Capture the output of `dir /B /S` with [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and use the [`~`-modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to remove the parent path:

   ```cmd
   (for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "C:\test\*.txt"') do echo/%%~nxI) > "C:\list.txt"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by excecuting the command:

```
dir /b > output.txt
```

This gives you a list with only the file names, without the file path.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
But I tried before, the text file will only show the folder name.

Comment: @DdwSs That is weird, If I run that cmd, it gives me the file names, make sure you excecute the command in the folder, step1: cd test, step2: dir /b > output.txt

Comment: I tried again, it only show the folder name...
Folder1 and Folder2
I use Win7 Pro to run this cmd, is it OS version to make the different?

Comment: @DdwSs Can you upload some screenshots of the folder and the output? Maybe an image of the tree /f command in the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it with a `FOR` loop is:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %D IN ('DIR /B "C:\test\Folder*"') DO (DIR /B "%~D\*.txt")
```

If there are specific directory names, you could:

```
FOR %D IN ("C:\test\Folder1" "C:\test\Folder2") DO (DIR /B "%~D\*.txt")
```